# swift access property of an object in Array, returns nil

Tags: ios, object, swift

I have been learning the swift language. I setup this vocabulary class and using this class to generate a new object "newWord". I put this object into a new Array "vocabularyListb". When I try to get the newWord.name property from the array, it returns "nil". So the question is how can I access the property of an Object that  resides in an Array?

```
class vocabulary{
  let name:String

  init(name: String){
    self.name = name  
  }
}

let vocabularyList1a = ["instigate", "constitution", "bellow", "jargon", "term"]

var vocabularyList1b = [AnyObject]()

var newWord = vocabulary(name: vocabularyList1a[0])

newWord.name

vocabularyList1b.append(newWord)

vocabularyList1b[0].name
```

Comment: Why is vocabularyList1b as [AnyObject] ? Shouldn't it be [vocabulary] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you instantiate your `vocabularyList1b` as `[AnyObject]`. But you actually want to have an array of `vocabulary` objects.

So you will have to change :

```
var vocabularyList1b = [AnyObject]()
```

To:

```
var vocabularyList1b = [vocabulary]()
```

After that you can access the `name` variable.